# lxsession-default-terminal does not open a terminal anymore (Lubuntu 18.04)

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, lxde, pcmanfm, lxsession

I am using Lubuntu 18.04
`lxsession-default-terminal` (which is used by PCManFM (F4) -> open Terminal in folder) does not open a Terminal-Window anymore.

(I can only see a flashing window [open and closes immediatelly])

This problem exists on **3** different PCs
(2x upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04, 1x fresh install as VM [minimal Desktop]).

**INFO:**
I know, PCManFM can be configured to use a different command to open a terminal.
 But I am curious why `lxsession-default-terminal` does not open a terminal anymore.
 Calling `lxsession-default-terminal` directly only outputs: `Launching terminal manager`

**EDIT:**
This is from the logfiles (`~/.cache/lxsession/Lubuntu/run.log`) after I hit F4 in PCManFM 
(see: `lxterminal exit with this type of exit: 0`):

(duplicate lines removed!)

```
Launching terminal manager
** Message: 12:20:49.616: dbus-lxde-session.vala:796: Start Terminal Manager
** Message: 12:20:49.618: app.vala:76: Launching lxterminal 

(lxterminal:1604): dbind-WARNING **: 12:20:49.652: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(lxterminal:1604): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:20:49.652: g_find_program_in_path: assertion 'program != NULL' failed

(lxterminal:1604): Vte-WARNING **: 12:20:49.716: (../../src/vtegtk.cc:1906):int vte_terminal_match_add_gregex(VteTerminal*, GRegex*, GRegexMatchFlags): runtime check failed: (g_regex_get_compile_flags(gregex) & G_REGEX_MULTILINE)

(lxterminal:1604): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:20:49.716: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed

** (lxpanel:901): WARNING **: 12:20:49.762: lxpanel : X error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)

(lxpanel:901): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:20:49.762: IA__gdk_window_get_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(lxpanel:901): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:20:49.762: IA__gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(lxpanel:901): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:20:49.762: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (lxpanel:901): WARNING **: 12:20:49.763: lxpanel : X error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)

(lxpanel:901): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:20:49.763: g_string_insert_len: assertion 'len == 0 || val != NULL' failed
** Message: 12:20:49.764: app.vala:130: lxterminal exit with this type of exit: 0

** (lxpanel:901): WARNING **: 12:20:49.765: lxpanel : X error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
```

Comment: I have a clean install of Lubuntu 18.04 in a VM. Pressing `F4` in `PCManFM` opens `lxterminal`. Pressing `Alt+F2` and selecting `lxsession-default-terminal` also opens `lxterminal`. So something may have gone wrong during the upgrade. If you wish, try renaming `~/.config` to `~/.config.bak`. Log out and log back in. If things work as they should, you know some file/folder in `~/.config` was messed up.

Comment: @DKBose Please see my edit. I tried also a fresh installation (Lubuntu 18.04). Same problem here.

Comment: Mine is a full install. I didn't choose the minimal option.

Comment: I see a lot of very similar errors in the same log file but `lxterminal` launches in both cases. This is the first time, we've had the minimal option and maybe there are some unintentional omissions?

Comment: Yes, LXTerminal launches (I can see a window trying to open)...but it closes immediately after 0.5 sec. (so, I only see a flashing [open/close] window when hitting F4)

Comment: Please try the full install in your VM.

Comment: I can try this, but I doubt this will help to make it work on my other 2 existing computers (which were upgraded from 17.10). I highly want to avoid a complete new installation of these 2 computers.

Comment: I suppose you also posted your question at https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=37779

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer, but my comment is longer than the maximum size.

I'm also affected. I did a distro upgrade to 18.04 (from 17.10), and then this issue started. Well, I haven't debugged enough, but I have the same symptoms as you.

I can use `lxsession-default-apps` to change the default terminal, but it doesn't matter. Clicking "Reload" (to open a new terminal from `lxsession-default-apps` interface), or running `lxsession-default-terminal` both fail the same way: a new window briefly shows and disappears.

`/usr/bin/lxsession-default-terminal` is actually a shell script that runs `dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="org.lxde.SessionManager" /org/lxde/SessionManager org.lxde.SessionManager.SessionLaunch string:"terminal_manager" string:"$PWD"`, which makes me believe there is something wrong within LXDE session manager.

I'm running LXDE with OpenBox. I can optionally run `compton`, but it doesn't change anything (other than having `compton` print dozens of `BadWindow` messages).

---

As a workaround, I can edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and remap the terminal shortcuts to `lxterminal` directly.

Answer (score 0):

On my install, I have the following options for default terminal manager:

- Disable
- Terminal emulator
- LXTerminal

If I set this to "LXTerminal", I have the problem you described above, including the same error messages. However, if I change it to "Terminal emulator", everything works as expected.

Of course, this doesn't explain the problem but will hopefully fix it for you too.